# how to parse contract method response

Tags: web3js

I'm writing a Dapp, which connect the ether web3 provided by metamask.

How should I handle the response from contract method? I mean some methods that doesn't need to send a transaction.

for example, In my contract there's a public uint field and a public address field.

the code to get the uint field

```
contractIns.uintField(function(err, result){
     if(err){
         //error
     } else {
         //the data is in result.c[0];
     }
});
```

however, the code to get the address field

```
contractIns.addressField(function(err, result) {
     if(err){
         //error
     } else {
         //the result is the data itself
     }
});
```

I mean, is there any documentation about the format of return value format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solidity has integer types (like uint) that are too big for the javascript numeric type, so to avoid losing important data web3 will wrap integer types in a [bignumber.js](https://mikemcl.github.io/bignumber.js/).

If you are sure the number is within the javascript range you can use the function `toNumber` to converto to a javascript numeric type.

```
contractIns.uintField(function(err, result){
     if(err){
         //error
     } else {
         //Use toNumber to convert to numeric type
         var myField = result.toNumber();
         console.log(myField);
     }
});
```